# Custom gallery layout with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, gallery

I'm trying to create this style of gallery layout with flexbox, but running into some trouble.

[image]

So far my code is putting two small ones and the large one in the top row, and then the second small ones on the bottom row.

Comment: Can you please paste your code snippet too? It will help us identify the issue.

Comment: You should use grid as it has easier implementation. Check some online grid visualiser tools for help

Comment: Use grid as mentioned:  **CSS Grid and Flexbox are layout models that share similarities and can be used together. The key difference is that CSS Grid can be used to create two-dimensional layouts, while Flexbox can only be used to create one-dimensional layouts. That means you can place components along the X- and Y-axis in CSS Grid and only one axis in Flexbox.** [Read more](https://blog.hubspot.com/website/css-grid-vs-flexbox)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1em;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="content">half</div>
    <div class="content">half</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item content">full</div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="content">half</div>
    <div class="content">half</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Html

```
        <div class"parent">
            <div class="leftContent"></div>
            <div class="centerContent"></div>
            <div class="rightContent"></div>
        </div>
```

Css

```
.parent{
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.leftContent{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.rightContent{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

add now the contents in the divs. i think this should work